# Getting FLAC format file iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudiorecorder

I want to record voice and after that get .flac format file, can I save recorded sound as flac? If yes - how to do it? I have tried, but only .caf available..

Comment: Why flac?   It is widely supported in the OSS community, but not so much beyond that.

Comment: This is a kind of quite actual question because online Google Speech Recognition service accepts only FLAC and SPEEX audio formats, both are not supported by iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no native support for FLAC in iOS

Check this: http://www.macworld.com/article/157310/2011/01/flac_on_ios.html

Comment: I saw ffmpeg supports converting to .flag on iPhone, do you know where I can download sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the file as a WAVE file instead of a caf file. Then you can use [libFLAC](http://flac.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flac/) and [wav_to_flac](https://github.com/jhurt/wav_to_flac) to convert it to FLAC encoded audio:

```
#include "wav_to_flac.h"

NSString *flacFile = //path to the output file
NSString *waveFile = //path to the wave input file
const char *wave_file = [waveFile UTF8String];
const char *flac_file = [flacFile UTF8String];
int conversionResult = convertWavToFlac(wave_file, flac_file);
// Do something with the file
```